# Access variable inside a function SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have been trying to access a variable from inside a function and am struggling to find a way to do so.

Below is an idea of what I am trying to achieve. For example, when the function testFunc is run, it will shuffle an array. I want to get the result of that array back into the body of the struct, but am struggling to do so.

Some ideas I have tried include binding variables but it seems gets confusing as I am relatively inexperienced. Is there a method to achieve this or would using the binding variables be the best way to go?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {

testFunc()

} 

func testFunc() {

var tester = ["a", "b", "c"].shuffled

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asperi just answered your question! but I do not think you need a function, you need to just access the array for shuffle, like this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(array, id:\.self) { item in
            
            Text(item)
            
        }
        
        Button("shuffle") {
            array.shuffle()
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply. I have tried that method before but for some reason, it comes up with a caution message saying the result of call to shuffled() is unused. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I have an idea! As I can see in your question, you are new to SwiftUI and you are thinking that you can run a Void in body of a View, which is wrong as Asperi mentioned! You are making that line of code but you are not process it to get run, see my code! it works perfectly because I am shuffling in action of a button! for sure your issue is not function, you need to study about SwiftUI in general.

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly! That is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much for all your help. I am slowly trying to learn but it's a lot to take in but I think I understand what you were saying. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help you always if I can.